# Can I varnish a laminate floor?

Tags: repair, flooring, laminate

I made a big hole in my laminate flooring. Thankfully, I've filled it and after many attempts managed to match the colour / pattern with some paints intended for fixing small scratches in wood furniture. The problem is this paint wipes off very easily. I don't fancy repainting the floor everytime I clean it, so I was wondering what I can put over it to keep it there? I've seen varnishes in the store, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Any finish made for hardwood floors should work.  It might change the paint match finish a bit so it does match exactly with the rest of the floor again.  Should try on waste pieces to be sure of the final result.  Even clear type finish will change the colour slightly, even just make it shinier than straight paint.  Bring a sample/type of paint used to the store to match to finish type.

Comment: If you truly have a laminate floor the top layer is plastic. Varnish will probably not play well with that. If you have filled the hole, find something that bonds with what you filled it with.